# Onclick() event for LI elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I'm currently trying to make my whole `li` element as the click event to navigate on my website and the script is still not working (no redirection or open in new tab{not in shown code} )

[ADDED, not clear]
No redirection whatsoever(which is what I want the redirection code to do obviously, hints the document.location), just staying still. Here is what console outputs :

```
top_bar.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: document.location is not a function(…)
TopBarClick @ top_bar.js:9
onclick @ accueil.html:75
```

(the html:75 is the `li` with `onclick` event and js:9 is the `document.location` part)
[/ADDED]

Here's the JS code related to it (with HTML and CSS) :

```js
    function TopBarClick(entier) {
        "use strict";
    
        switch (entier) {
        {...}
        case 2:
            document.location("/index.html");
            break;
        {...}
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

```css
    #banner li{
        list-style: none;
        width:25%;
        height:100%;
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        z-index:100;
    
    }

    #banner > li{
        background-color: #00a0e6;
        float:left;
        z-index:100;

    }

    #banner > li:nth-child(2n){
        background-color: #0883b9;
        width:50%;
        z-index:100;
            cursor:pointer;
    }
```

```html
    <ul id="banner">
                <li><a href="../../../../../accueil.html" target="_self">Accueil</a></li>
                <li onclick="TopBarClick(2)"><a href="../../../../../index.html">Index</a></li>
                <li><a >Contact</a>
    </ul>
```

**PS:**
In "not working (no redirection or open in new tab{not in shown code} )"

"not working" is the status.

"(no redirection or open in new tab{not in shown code} )" is what it ain't doing and should be doing (which should've been obvious for all but apparently basic semantic and syntax is too much).

Comment: You should not have the links stored twice (once in code and once in the links). That is a maintenance problem Just find the link inside the LI when you get an LI click.

Comment: Q: Are you using jQuery on your website at all? This would become a trivial & short piece of code if jQuery was an option.

Comment: I do use it (not on the homepage at the moment) on some pages

Comment: **Not working** is not describing the problem. When testing your code, the `<li>` when clicked redirects to a site, is that not what you want? You should add what it is that is currently happening and what behavior you actually expect to happen. Otherwise nobody knows what is broken and for all we know, everything works fine.

Comment: Is the description clear now ?

Comment: PS: you probably clicked on the A not on the LI  because when I run the snippet and click the LI it only show an error

Comment: Your error is that `document.location` is not a function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location
Use it as a string property e.g. `document.location = "/index.html";`

Comment: Thx solved the problem

Comment: May @FrançoisWahl cease the hold so :
1)@GoneCoding could properly put the problem solution in answer section
2)he could allow me to tick the answer
3)he could allow himself to read the post again to see how clear it was (without the EDIT and PSs and then with all of them)
4)he could tell me where we buy the Question+ DLC

Comment: @VoltraNeo Just to be clear, I voted for it to be put on hold before you edited the exact definition of what was not working and not after. hold simply means to give OP a chance to clarify the question. Now that all edits are there I gladly revoke the hold, though I can't do that alone and only vote for it. Also, please refrain from adding "rants" into questions/answers.

Comment: cf PS#1

PS: no rants, just facts. It was clear, syntax clear just not in mathematical form

Comment: @VoltraNeo Insulting people calling the community non intelligent, ranting about having enough of this site is not constructive and not relevant to the question, thank you. Keep it on topic and professional please.

Comment: That is true but :
 saying it was incomplete whereas there was enough + saying "not working" isn't enough whereas there were stuff in parentheses explaining what exactly + put hold on it because of this invalid reasons + magic edit seems unprofessional.

I asked my question, you didn't know neither basic syntax nor basic semantic and still found I was not explaining my problem correctly. Putting on hold should NOT be subjective but purely objective (problem definition missing, etc ...) not just "I can't read parentheses and stop before them"

Comment: + You said it "worked" when you clicked on it but it doesn't. You might have clicked on the text which (big surprise) is not the LI part but the A part. Maybe you have trouble reading CSS and HTML ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is that `document.location` is not a function http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location

Use it as a string property

e.g.

```
document.location = "/index.html";
```